# Fit conjunction (!.) applied to expand

Tags: j

Is it possible to specify a default value for `expand` with `!.`, the fit conjunction? Normally, it is possible to specify a default fill value for `#`, but what about `#^:_1`?

For example, something like

```
    empty =. <0 0$''
    r =. 0 1 0 1 expand!.empty 'foo';'bar' NB. Actually a domain error
++---+---++
||foo|bar||
++---+---++
    $ each r
+---+-+-+---+
|0 0|3|3|0 0|
+---+-+-+---+
```

All I've tried throws domain errors:

```
expand!.empty
#^:_1!.empty
#!.empty^:_1
(#!.empty)^:_1
```

Comment: what kind of language is this

Comment: @yes123:  This is J, which is evolved from and similar to APL.

Comment: And yes, my bias for J5 over J6 shows in the boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to use the fit conjunction to alter the fill for `expand` (`#^:_1`)

The technique I do know how to use is to write an equivalent to `expand` for which we specify the fill element.

The following code allows custom expansion such as you've described. It has been written to work with version 5, since you indicated you rely on that, but I have only tested it under version 6.  As usual, this is likely susceptible to further refinement.

```
   xpand=: 1 :'((retention j. expansion)@:[ #!.u prep@:])'
   prep=: ,~ {.
   retention=: 0:, +/ # 1:
   expansion=: [:forwarddifference [:tallyzeros [:partition [:<\ pad
   forwarddifference=: 2&(-~/\)
   tallyzeros=: +/ @: -. &>
   partition=: #~ (1: = {:)&>
   pad=: 1&([,~ ,)

   NB. example of use
   empty =. <0 0$''
   ]r=. 0 1 1 0 empty xpand 'foo';'bar'
┌┬───┬───┬┐
││foo│bar││
└┴───┴───┴┘
   $ each r
┌───┬─┬─┬───┐
│0 0│3│3│0 0│
└───┴─┴─┴───┘
```

Since posting the original answer I obtained a more concise alternative:

```
   xpand =: 1 :' index @:[ { u,~] '
   index =:  retain + insert
   retain=:  I.@:] }~  [:i.+/
   insert=:  +/ * -.
```

Note that the `u,~]` portion is not compatible with version 5. Use `],u"_` instead for compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

```
0 1 0 1 expand f.!.empty 'foo';'bar' NB. with f. works fine
```

```
++---++---+
||foo||bar|
++---++---+
```

The trick is to use `f.` or `#^:_1` anonymously, so that `!.` sees `#^:_1` as its left argument, instead of `expand`.  Fit isn't as smart as it could be.

Comment: Oh, nice one! I think I like it better than kaleidic's.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work in J 5. It's a good answer, but I'm carrying this J 5 code like some carcass and I'm stuck to it until it rots away or actually is migrated to J 6 (and there are sadly more subtleties to it than just changing `x.` to `x`).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be:

```
   inv=: ^:_1
   1 0 1 0 1 ((#inv #\) { 'z'&,@]) 'abc'
azbzc
```

Replace the nouns with whatever nouns you want to be working with...

Thus:

```
   fillExpand=:1 :'(#inv #\) { m&,@]'
   empty=:<i.0 0
   0 1 0 1 empty fillExpand ;:'foo bar'
++---++---+
||foo||bar|
++---++---+
   $&.>0 1 0 1 empty fillExpand ;:'foo bar'
+---+-+---+-+
|0 0|3|0 0|3|
+---+-+---+-+
```

That said, note that #\ is inefficient under version 5.  In version 5, I would replace #\ with 1: + i.@#

That said, note that Dan Bron's suggestion #!.empty^:_1 works fine for me, and I thought should work fine in version 5.